# Future in the past: would come or came?

Tags: tenses

The sentence below is from the short story *Death of the Island Doctor* by [Gene Wolfe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Wolfe). The two students ("they" in the sentence) are discussing what they will tell the professor ("Dr. Insula") when they come to his seminar again next week:

> And when they had cooled the beer in the leaf-brown river, and eaten
> the sandwiches they had brought, they paddled back to the spot where
> they had parked the Toyota, debating how they could tell Dr. Insula he
> had been mistaken about the island **when they came next week**—how they
> could tell him there was no magic there.

The clause "when they came next week" is in the future from their perspective, which is the past. So shouldn't the normative way of writing it be "when they would come next week"? Is the sentence correct/idiomatic/strange as written?

Comment: When the students were discussing how to tell Dr Insula they would not have said "When we will come next week" because  they were discussing something that they were already committed to so they would have used the base form of the verb "When we come next week". When we look back at their discussion and turn it into reported speech  we retain the same structure so we don't say "...when they would come next week" we use the simple past "...when they came next week".  It's perfectly correct and idiomatic.

Comment: Personally I would have preferred "the next week" in the reported speech because "next week" means the week after the current one and my next week isn't the same as theirs. It's not a big issue but I think the sentence would be clearer.

Comment: Just backshift one tense... **Real time**: *They are debating how they can tell Dr. Insula—when they report to him next week—that there is no magic here.* **Past reported**: *They were debating how they could tell Dr. Insula—when they reported to him the following week—that there was no magic there.*